# What does 'Messages available' in the AWS SQS console mean?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

What is 'Messages available' in the AWS SQS console?

I'm familiar with message queueing concepts, and 'messages in flight' seems obvious - that's the amount of unprocesed messages on the queue. But what does a message being 'available' mean? How can a message be available or not available? I've read the [SQS docs and FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/faqs/) and can't find an answer.

[image]

Note I marked this as a possible dupe of [Why do SqS messages sometimes remain in-flight on queue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19792881/why-do-sqs-messages-sometimes-remain-in-flight-on-queue) myself, but that question is focused on the definition of 'in flight' not 'available'.

Comment: *"and 'messages in flight' seems obvious - that's the amount of unprocesed messages on the queue"* - no. Those are the message currently being processed. The "Messages available" are the messages that are there and nobody is even attempting to process them.

Comment: Damn. I think of MQ as a transport mechanism, and 'in flight' means 'in transit' not 'has arrived and is being processed'. I appreciate you're right (from [other answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19792881/why-do-sqs-messages-sometimes-remain-in-flight-on-queue?rq=1)) but AWS's analogies here are way off what logic would dictate. @luk2302 do you want to add a reference and make this an answer?

Answer (score 1):

**Answering my own question to help others:**

As @luk2302's comment mentions (Luk feel free to add your own answer), my understanding on 'in flight' was incorrect. [AWS doesn't use the term 'in flight' in their API docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-available-cloudwatch-metrics.html) however those docs do have some useful references:

**Messages Available** seems to correspond to `ApproximateNumberOfMessagesVisible` in the API. This is

> The number of messages available for retrieval from the queue.

**Messages in flight** is `ApproximateNumberOfMessagesNotVisible`

> Messages are considered to be in flight if they have been sent to a client but have not yet been deleted or have not yet reached the end of their visibility window.